# status: false } has no method 'save' Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my code to update :

```
 mongodb.model("Participant").find({ channel: response.channel }, function (err, doc){
                  doc.status = 1;
                  doc.save();
                  });
```

And i am getting this error:

```
                  doc.save();
                      ^
TypeError: Object { _id: 55f365f32d051f10024d9c9d,
  event: 'ConfbridgeJoin',
  channel: 'SIP/192.168.236.15-00000213',
  uniqueid: '1442014697.1157',
  conference: '0090000218',
  calleridnum: '0090000219',
  calleridname: '0090000219',
  __v: 0,
  status: false } has no method 'save'
```

it errors status: false } has no method 'save'

Comment: Try `findOne` instead of `find`. Your're trying to save an array, not a document.

Comment: it works . . thanks you @BrianShamblen:)